# $[[x,y],z]\neq[x,[y,z]]$, nervertheless $[[A,B],C]=[A,[B,C]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A direct computation yelds to $[[x,y],z]\neq[x,[y,z]]$; nervertheless if $A,B,C$ are subgroups of a larger group $G$, I "conjectured" we have $[[A,B],C]=[A,[B,C]]$.

I think it's right because every commutator of weight $n$ (whose $n$ elements stay in $G$) stay in $\gamma_n(G)$ (which is defined recursively as $[\gamma_{n-1}(G),G]$ and $\gamma_1(G):=G$). Am I right?

Comment: In your second paragraph, you have chosen $A=B=C=G$. In case $A=C$, your conjecture is right. Generally it is not.

Comment: Related: The [three subgroups lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Counterexamples:

Here is a small counterexample: Let $G=S_3$, let $A=B=\langle (1,2) \rangle$, $C=\langle(2,3)\rangle$. Then $[A,B] = 1$, $[B,C] = A_3$, $[[A,B],C]=1$, and $[A,[B,C]]=A_3$.

Here is one where everything is normal: Let $G=S_3$, let $A=B=G$, $C=A_3$. Then $[A,B]=A_3$, $[B,C]=A_3$, $[[A,B],C]=1$, and $[A,[B,C]]=A_3$.

#### A time it works:

Here is one time it works: Since $[A,B]=[B,A]$ (because $[a,b] = [b,a]^{-1}$ and $H=H^{-1}$ for subgroups), $[[A,B],C] = [[B,A],C] = [ C, [B,A] ]$, if $A=C$, and so $[[A,B],C] = [ A, [B,C] ]$.

#### Correct general statement:

If $[[A,B],C] \leq N\unlhd G$ and $[[B,C],A] = [A,[B,C]] \leq N$, then $[[C,A],B] \leq N$. If $A,B,C \unlhd G$, then one can take $N=[[A,B],C]$ to be the normal subgroup. These sorts of statements are called the [three subgroup lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma) and they follow from the Hall–Witt identity. Be careful, that if $N$ is not normal, the statement needs to be (horribly) modified.

Comment: (Also thanks to @user1729 PhD for mentioning three subgroups :-)